# Adobe Flash not working in Opera

Tags: google-chrome, video, browser, flash, opera

I'm using Opera as my browser on a Windows 8.1, 64-bit computer, and recently, when I try to watch online videos i.e. on BBC iPlayer, the video shows a message saying "Adobe Flash Player is out of date".

I have tried updating it, but still get the same message. I can watch those exact same videos using Google Chrome without a problem, so I am wondering if this is some sort of virus/ browser hijack? Or is it possibly that the version of Opera I'm using doesn't support Flash? (I'm using version 32.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was some sort of virus- the message being shown on the videos stating that Flash was out of date was coming from something other than the browser- some sort of plugin or something that had been installed. I was able to remove this using Avira antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Open about:plugins and click details on top right portion. Check which version of flash player you have. Disable the older one if you have two.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick up the latest version of flash Player from http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html and install it manually. Things should be back to normal then.